# What is the best practise for MariaDB mysqldump configurations of large databases?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump, my.cnf

### Problem

We have a large database (MariaDB 10.3) and `mysqldump` takes 2-3 hours to complete a full database dump, and it's also causing downgrade in application performance during the dump process.

### Attempt so far

After some research, we found out that the `[mysqldump]` section can be added in the `my.cnf` file. Also options like `quick` , `max_allowed_packet = 512M` can be added.

If we can add `single-transaction` also along with the above settings, then the database will not be locked during the dump and it should speed up the application.

So are these entries appropriate for `my.cnf`?

```
[mysqldump]
single-transaction
quick
max_allowed_packet = 512M
```

Answer (score 1):

All the options you mention can be specified on `mysqldump`'s [command line](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/), for what it's worth.  That may be a better way to write a self-documenting backup process than stuffing those items into (hiding them in) a configuration file.

And, if you have performance problems with your dump operation you can try omitting the `single-transaction` option. If your database application uses transactions to ensure consistency between multiple tables, you need `single-transaction` for your backup.  Otherwise your backup operation will interfere less with your other database workload.

If you're not doing so already, try running the backup from the same machine where the database is hosted.  Or use the `--compress` option. Or both. For a big database, the network traffic created by a backup is significant, and these suggestions can reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If your database structure is relatively static then dump it separately (once), and dump only tables data using `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` - this is more fast.

Of course you need:

- create a script (the best way - an event procedure) which dumps all (or only changeable) tables data
- create a script (maybe as stored procedure in structure dump) which restores the data from this dump taking into account that relational data must be restored in "one then many" order strictly

Comment: We won't have much options here and its daily cron job to take backup. My question was, asked parameters could be added in my.cnf or not? Db having all tables in innodb engine.

Comment: @EternalSunShine I doubt that any my.ini parameters adjustment may improve (maybe, very-very slightly, not more). And I'm sure that the technique described will improve at least twice.